# How do I set it back to proper language

Tags: language

I pressed something ( not sure what) and my elementary system language changed into something I can't understand.

How do I set it back to English?

See attached screenshot[image]

Comment: This is not a language, this is a special font elementary uses to obfuscate text in screenshots. You were probably taking a screenshot and it got stuck. I guess this should be gone after you logout and login again. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

First open **Terminal** and type the following command:

```
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Second logout and login again or reboot your machine.